# Angular 2, template error breaks simple site

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to modify the code from a NG2 lesson to make a dynamic spotify player in NG2.  When I add `<h1>anything</h1>` to my template in app.component.js it works.  When I add in + ` the code gives this error

```
zone.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'spotifyiframeplayer' is not a known element:
1. If 'spotifyiframeplayer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'spotifyiframeplayer' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h1>Spotify Iframe Player</h1>[ERROR ->]<spotifyiframeplayer></spotifyiframeplayer>"): AppComponent@0:30 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
'spotifyiframeplayer' is not a known element:
1. If 'spotifyiframeplayer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'spotifyiframeplayer' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h1>Spotify Iframe Player</h1>[ERROR ->]<spotifyiframeplayer></spotifyiframeplayer>"): AppComponent@0:30
    at TemplateParser.parse (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8530:21)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16905:53)
    at https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:85
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:49)
    at e.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js:1:15936)
    at n.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js:1:13323)
    at https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js:1:11425
    at e.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js:1:16565)
    at n.runTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js:1:13925)o @ zone.min.js:1a @ zone.min.js:1a @ zone.min.js:1
zone.min.js:1 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)o @ zone.min.js:1a @ zone.min.js:1a @ zone.min.js:1
```

[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cQtqBijQv6GyKwUqz0Jd)
I'm not sure how to fix this error.  I have checked and the element is only mentioned one time in the sample code and works for that project.

@galvon (this is also on the plunker)

```
(function(app) {
  var Component = ng.core.Component;

  app.AppComponent = Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
      `
      <h1>Spotify Iframe Player</h1>
      <spotifyiframeplayer></spotifyiframeplayer>
      `
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function AppComponent() { }
  });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Please post your template, something there is not valid (syntax)

Comment: Where do you define `spotifyiframeplayer` component. You should add this component to `declarations` property of yout module

Comment: I'll try declaring it in app.component.js

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the help!  I'll try to pick through this and find the steps I missed.  I'm guessing I will get that error every time I don't declare a component with a template.  Adding in the blank undefined element was not going to work?

Comment: You should either specify the exact components used in angular2 application within `declarations` property or use `schema: CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` then Angular2 also won't complain anymore

Comment: I'll test that out.  I saw it in the error message but wasn't really sure what to think.  Declaring the component seemed like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use **+** to append strings.

to use **multiline HTML**, you can use **backtick** (find in your keyboard - **`**
) as shown below,

```
template:
      '<h1>Spotify Iframe Player</h1>' +
      '<spotifyiframeplayer></spotifyiframeplayer>'
```

change it to

```
template:
      `
      <h1>Spotify Iframe Player</h1>
      <spotifyiframeplayer></spotifyiframeplayer>
      `
```

**NOTE** : Other than this, your plunker is incomplete so even after this change don't expect plunker to run as you don't have `spotifyiframeplayer` component implementation.

Comment: trying to get that to work... seems to have the same issue.  I put in back-ticks and tried to copy \ paste.  Doesn't seem to be working on plunker either

Comment: Not sure what I am missing, guess I will start over again with the example

Comment: @drew4452862 you don't have `spotifyiframeplayer` component implementation.

Comment: @PankajParkar Might be ` ` so it works with typescript?  guessing

Comment: @drew4452862 no it can work with `+` as well, here is [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p7z6509nHlgMO5GBNp5K?p=preview) **(edited plunkr created by yurzui, thanks :))**

Comment: It works because modern browsers understrand es6 features

Comment: Yeah, ES6 seems to be working.  The example I was working with mentioned a few times that they were only using ES5.  I got really confused because I didn't see that the component needed to be declared.

Comment: @PankajParkar I didn't see your comment. I wrote don't use + sign as (generally) template will not have one or two lines but will have so many lines (That was kinda suggestion) . Other thing In Note, I specified that you don't have an implemenation of declared component , so don't expect it to run and I din't invest my time as I don't know how to declare and use that component with JS.

Comment: I saw your answer when you had **You can't use + to append strings.** in answer. I guess you edited afterwards